# cant figure out mod_rewrite for php query string =/

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

here is my website

http://www.coolcodez.net/ios/nicucalc

notice when you click on pages on the nav you get urls like

http://www.coolcodez.net/ios/nicucalc/index.php?page=features

I put an .htaccess file in my nicucalc directory.  I want the urls to look like this

http://www.coolcodez.net/ios/nicucalc/features

even better would be

http://www.coolcodez.net/nicucalc/features

here is my htaccess file.  It's never working properly..

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1/? [R=301,L]
```

what am i doing wrong.  explanation as well please

also note:  this folder is located inside of a wordpress installation folder.  not sure if that htaccess file would be affecting mine somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule that you have redirects requests for `index.php` to `/features/` (or whatever the "page" is). This is fine in and of itself but you need something that rewrites it internally *back* to index.php. Because of that you need 2 rules, one to redirect (matches request) and one to internally rewrite (matches URI):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ios/nicucalc/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /ios/nicucalc/index\.php\?page=([^&\ ]+)&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /ios/nicucalc/%1?%2 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The first rule matches against the request, this looks like:

```
GET /ios/nicucalc/index.php?page=features HTTP/1.1
```

The "features" is captured and backreferenced in the rule using `%1`. The second rule first checks if the request points to an existing file or directory. If it doesn't then the URI is captured and then rewritten to `index.php` and the URI gets passed to the script via the "page" parameter.

Comment: this doesnt seem to be working.  i have this implemented in my htaccess file.  you can try going to urls on the site right now

Comment: @hamobi these rules expect to be in the htaccess file in `/ios/nicucalc/`

Comment: @hamobi sorry, I left out some `!` in front of the `-f` and `-d`

Comment: now its working.  im going to accept your answer but if you could give a detailed explanation that would be great!